# Вывести списки, названия которых находиться в другом списке

Tags: python, list, циклы, переменные

Я сейчас не могу вывести данные списков, название которых находятся в другом списке. ниже пример:

```
all_masses = ['rest1', 'rest2', 'rest3', 'rest4', 'rest5']
    
rest1 = {'res1': 'key1', 'res1': 'key1'}
rest2 = {'res2': 'key2', 'res2': 'key2'}
rest3 = {'res3': 'key3', 'res3': 'key3'}
rest4 = {'res4': 'key4', 'res4': 'key4'}
rest5 = {'res5': 'key5', 'res5': 'key5'}
    
print(rest3)
for i in all_masses:
    print(i)
```

В отдельном принте по конкретному названию данные выводятся. Вот когда провожу их по циклу из списка с теми же названиями, выводятся лишь эти самые названия. Возможно где-то что-то нужно указать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например так:

```py
all_masses = ['rest1', 'rest2', 'rest3', 'rest4', 'rest5']
    
rest1 = {'res1': 'key1', 'res1': 'key1'}
rest2 = {'res2': 'key2', 'res2': 'key2'}
rest3 = {'res3': 'key3', 'res3': 'key3'}
rest4 = {'res4': 'key4', 'res4': 'key4'}
rest5 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}

for i in all_masses:
    print(locals()[i]) # Locals() преобразование строки в имя переменной
```

P.S. И со словарями у вас ошибка так как ключи должны быть уникальны. Поэтому в цикле `rest1` будет как {'res1': 'key1'}, а не `{'res1': 'key1', 'res1': 'key1'}`. Переделанный `rest5` будет отображаться корректно.